# Converting US date to Japanese

Tags: java, javascript, xslt

I am working on Multi-language site which need the date to be displayed in japanese language set. I have US date like 12-29-2010 which need to be displayed in japanese as 2010年12月29日. I am using XSLT 3432 to do. Can you please let me know how I can do that.

---

I have to convert english date to japanese from the db, which has many different month/day/year and is updated regularly. This is just an example I have provided.

I am using XSLT and can use Javascript in it

Comment: Are you really using java or just javascript?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an easy XSLT solution. :)

Comment: Please stop "answering" to add more details.  You can edit your question to add content, or leave comments on answers when appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pUSDate" select="'12-29-2010 '"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select=
  "concat(substring($pUSDate,7,4),
          '年',
          substring($pUSDate,1,2),
          '月',
          substring($pUSDate,4,2),
          '日'
         )
  "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on any XML document (not used), produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
2010年12月29日
```

Comment: I have to convert english date to japanese from the db, which has many different month/day/year and is updated regularly. This is just an example I have provided.

Comment: @m_gupta: And my answer provides the solution exactly to the problem you present.

Comment: How ? Can yo please explain. As 29th December will be Wednesday which is represented as 日, which will need to change as per the date it 30th it should change to thrusday.

Comment: @m_gupta: If you provide the meaning and all possible values of the Japanese words that will need to be displayed, then an XSLT 2.0 solution is straight-forward. But this would be completely new question -- please ask a new question with all this data provided.